# Docker image built does not seem to commit RUN commands

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building an image with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN mkdir -pv /app && mkdir -pv /app/source
```

When it finishes and I log into the image, the directories do not exist.
Here is the output from the build and from logging in and listing the directories:

```
BOSM00645241A:docker_home i858847$ docker build -t my-test-image .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  78.02MB
Step 1/2 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
16.04: Pulling from library/ubuntu
7b8b6451c85f: Pull complete 
ab4d1096d9ba: Pull complete 
e6797d1788ac: Pull complete 
e25c5c290bde: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:e547ecaba7d078800c358082088e6cc710c3affd1b975601792ec701c80cdd39
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:16.04
 ---> a51debf7e1eb
Step 2/2 : RUN mkdir -pv /app
 ---> Running in 9bc2264df0de
mkdir: created directory '/app'
Removing intermediate container 9bc2264df0de
 ---> f0b0c0a4e266
Successfully built f0b0c0a4e266
Successfully tagged my-test-image:latest
BOSM00645241A:docker_home i858847$ docker run -it --name my-test-image --rm bash
Unable to find image 'bash:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/bash
4fe2ade4980c: Pull complete 
57ab8b6a12dc: Pull complete 
f5cb10ae9311: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:360cdc0a48755a2701ed82156cd27d9e9f1a1f52c84b3b03a794d78f115c7e0f
Status: Downloaded newer image for bash:latest
bash-4.4# ls
bin    dev    etc    home   lib    media  mnt    proc   root   run    sbin   srv    sys    tmp    usr    var
bash-4.4#
```

It appears that the directories were created but they don't exist in the image

Comment: You are running a container named `my-test-image` from an image named `bash`; you are not running the container you built.  Try `docker run --rm -it my-test-image bash` (with no `--name` and with your image name as the first non-option argument).

Comment: Wow, that was exactly the problem, thanks Dave!

Comment: For some reason I don't have the ability to accept/upvote your answer but it should be the accepted answer. Thanks again Dave!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN mkdir -pv /app && mkdir -pv /app/source
```

Then you have to build that image:

```
docker build -t my-test-image -f ./Dockerfile .
```

Then You need to start container

```
docker run --rm -it my-test-image --name my-test-container bash
```

Parameters:

--it interactive

--rm remove container after you exit from it

--name name for your container

bash command you want to start in container

Comment: Thanks Edmhs, as you and Dave mention it was my my run command was incorrect.